# What happens over time if my CloudWatch alarms go to an SNS Topic but that topic has no subscriptions?

Tags: cloudwatch-alarms

I have some CloudWatch alarms that I need to set up and I only want alerts from a composite alarm (more than one of the components making up the composite alarm are set to ALARM)

I do not want to receive alarms from the individual components of this composite alarm because this would only inform us of a transitory condition that usually self-resolves.

My quesstion is, If a create an SNS Topic called "Unmonitored" for example and have those component alarms get sent to that topic do these alarms start to accumulate over time and how does AWS handle this?

I couldn't find any information on SNS lifespan or what happens to messages sent to an SNS topic when there are no subscriptions to that topic set up.

Edit: as a test I created a CloudWatch alarm with an SNS Topic that has no subscriptions and I get this message in the console:

Warning: "This action sends a message to an SNS topic with no endpoints or the endpoints are in a different account."

Which is to be expected.